# How to solve "unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted"

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I tried to install angular-cli, but I found this warn:

> unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted"(OS windows 10).

I am beginner in Angular, so I am expecting simple solution to solve this.

Error message screenshot:
[image: Error message]

Comment: `fsevents` is ***optional***, and is only available on MacOS.  It's perfectly safe to ignore this warning.

Comment: sometimes it can cause errors... if anyone runs into this, can refer to this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48898312/npm-error-unsupported-platform-for-fsevents-when-deploying-to-azure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a `Warning`, so no need to take any further action. Go ahead and run your code.

Answer (score 2):

Create an `optionalDependencies` in package.json instead of `devDependencies`:

```
"optionalDependencies": {
    "fsevents": "*"
}
```